# Add lead attachments to email template without Apex / VisualForce

Tags: email, workflow, attachment, template

I have set up a workflow to send an email to the lead owner on lead creation. I would like to add the lead's attachments to the email. Without VisualForce or Apex please, as I am a mere mortal with no developer skills. Something similar already exists in cases / knowledge: you can add {!Case.Articles_as_PDFs} in the email template.
Thanks.
Eric